# Server v8.0 at localhost fail to start

Tags: tomcat, startup

I have few questions to ask you.

I have installed Apache Tomcat v8.0.15, I don't have any problems with installation. But when I used to run my servlet program in Eclipse I got a pop-up error saying 2 different kind of errors. one is related to the combination of ports (saying the ports are already in process) and another is Server v8.0 at `localhost` fail to start. Can you please suggest me how to fix these.

I referred to the related question & answers in this website. But even then I could not resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you moving from a previous version of Tomcat to new one? Is another Tomcat running on your maching? Did you change the server.xml file in the conf sub-directory?

Comment: First check port usage by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows  and get information about which process is using it.